# Cannot read property 'compile' of undefined. Failed to start new react-native project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

I am following `Getting Started` section on React Native's website. I can't start the app generated using `expo init Project2` command. This is what I get when I run `npm start`

```
Pawes-MacBook-Pro:Project2 pawel$ npm start

> empty-project-template@ start /Users/pawel/Projects/react/Project2
> expo start

[23:31:11] Starting project at /Users/pawel/Projects/react/Project2
[23:31:11] Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
[23:31:11] Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)
[23:31:14] TypeError: Cannot read property 'compile' of undefined
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! empty-project-template@ start: `expo start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the empty-project-template@ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/pawel/.npm/_logs/2018-11-25T22_31_14_188Z-debug.log
```

Full `debug.log`:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v10.13.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle empty-project-template@~prestart: empty-project-template@
6 info lifecycle empty-project-template@~start: empty-project-template@
7 verbose lifecycle empty-project-template@~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle empty-project-template@~start: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/pawel/Projects/react/Project2/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
9 verbose lifecycle empty-project-template@~start: CWD: /Users/pawel/Projects/react/Project2
10 silly lifecycle empty-project-template@~start: Args: [ '-c', 'expo start' ]
11 silly lifecycle empty-project-template@~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle empty-project-template@~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: empty-project-template@ start: `expo start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
14 verbose pkgid empty-project-template@
15 verbose cwd /Users/pawel/Projects/react/Project2
16 verbose Darwin 17.7.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
18 verbose node v10.13.0
19 verbose npm  v6.4.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error empty-project-template@ start: `expo start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the empty-project-template@ start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Expo developer tools open on my Chrome, but there is this message: `Expo Developer Tools is disconnected from Expo CLI. Use the expo start command to start the CLI again.`

When I try `expo start` command (instead of `npm start`) I get similar result, but with a little less detailed CLI output:

```
Pawes-MacBook-Pro:Project2 pawel$ expo start
[23:32:52] Starting project at /Users/pawel/Projects/react/Project2
[23:32:52] Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
[23:32:52] Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)
[23:32:55] TypeError: Cannot read property 'compile' of undefined
```

Comment: Seems to have happened very recently. Someone created this github issue https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/213

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: Reinstall your `expo-cli` installation (eg. running `npm un -g expo-cli && npm i -g expo-cli`), the issue has been solved.

---

4 hours prior to creation of [the first issue](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/213) describing the problem, a new release of the `joi` package has been published (`14.3.0`). `expo-cli` [uses Joi](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/blob/9cafca638c378cf9223c1a09e7bc3b3740571280/packages/xdl/src/UrlUtils.js#L188) to validate some options argument passed into `constructUrlAsync` function. However, `expo-cli` wasn't using `joi.validate` directly, [it was wrapped](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/blob/9cafca638c378cf9223c1a09e7bc3b3740571280/packages/xdl/src/UrlUtils.js#L21) with `promisify`.

When [this commit](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/commit/ae6031d86677acae9e3f3fa9c289f29da0dd485e) landed in `joi`, first published in `joi@14.3.0` it broke integration with `promisify`. This, obviously, broke `xdl` dependency too, which in turn broke `expo-cli`.

We've [hotfixed](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/commit/8a340e3b28c242b520ab704455db6762ab612a87) the problem changing `joi` dependency requirement from `^14.0.4` to `14.0.4` and publishing `expo-cli@2.4.1`. The real solution came in [this pull request](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/pull/215), removing wrapping `joi.validate` with `promisify`.